# Regex to transform SVG path to raphael.js path format

Tags: regex, svg, raphael

For reasons of compatibility, I'm converting a SVG interactive map of the US to a Javascript-backed one.  In order to do this, I need to convert the given SVG paths to a JSON file.

An example path listing is

```
<path 
  d="M 404.13498,227.558 L 407.75898,227.324 L 407.95298,228.019 L 408.99798,
     231.791 L 409.07498,232.061 L 405.21798,232.503 L 404.57198,232.58 L 404.13498,
     227.558" 
  id="01111" 
  inkscape:label="Randolph, AL" 
</path>
```

What I'd like to do is convert this to the format

```
['01111', 'Randolph, AL', 
   'M727,410L734,409L734,410L736,417L736,418L729,419L728,419L727,410']
```

I know the example results are off; its due to the example map undergoing a linear expansion.  What I'm interested in is converting

```
M 404.13498,227.558 L 407.75898
```

into

```
M404, 227L407 ... ect
```

Regular expressions are my big weakness when it comes to text manipulation, and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Where did you get the values in the results? It seems that the results came from a different source path... Could you also please specify the logic -- which number comes from which part?

Comment: Regex are used to match something. I would not use a regex for this. Instead write a program that uses an XML library to read the file and then writes it to another file. After all there could be comments and so on in the XML.

Comment: @Jerry, the example given is from http://jebruner.com/2011/11/how-to-build-an-interactive-map-with-open-source-tools/  I'm not sure how he did the data transformation, but he does state that the new values are the result of a linear expansion of the original map.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly, this is SVG markup from a US county map available on wikimedia Commons.  There are no comments in the markup.

Comment: You could perhaps use [this regex](http://www.regex101.com/r/uP9zS0), but ah, I don't think I know enough javascript to sort it all out after extracting them :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

I would do this in two steps. First gather each of the paths in the string. Second remove the text from each of the strings you don't want retained.

**First Regex**

This captures all the attributes from the path without regard for their order in the tag. It also skips over some problematic issues where attribute values may contain strings which look like actual tags.

```
<path\s
(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sd=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))
(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sid=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))
(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sinkscape:label=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))
```

**Second Regex**

This will only be applied to the `d` attribute, and it basically replaces all the spaces decimal portion of each digit, and new line characters.

Regex: `(?<=\w|\s)\s|\.\d+|[\r\n"]`

Replace with: nothing

The other fields will simply have their double quotes removed.

## Example

I'm not a javascript programmer, however in powershell I'd approach the problem like this:

**Code**

```
$String = '<path 
  d="M 404.13498,227.558 L 407.75898,227.324 L 407.95298,228.019 L 408.99798,
     231.791 L 409.07498,232.061 L 405.21798,232.503 L 404.57198,232.58 L 404.13498,
     227.558" 
  id="01111" 
  inkscape:label="Randolph, AL" 
>
</path>
'

[regex]$FirstRegex = @'
<path\s(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sd=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sid=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sinkscape:label=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))
'@

$FirstRegex.matches($String) | foreach {

    $d = $_.Groups[1].Value -replace '(?<=\w|\s)\s|\.\d+|[\r\n"]', ""
    $id = $_.Groups[2].Value -replace '"', ""
    $label = $_.Groups[3].Value -replace '"', ""
    Write-Host "['$id', '$label', '$d']"
    } # next match
```

**Output**

```
['01111', 'Randolph, AL', 'M404,227L407,227L407,228L408,231L409,232L405,232L404,232L404,227']
```